# What's the shortest Small-size humanoid ever published, so I can Alter Self into one?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, creature-size

I'm looking for the shortest official humanoid creature I can transform into with the second level wizard spell *alter self*.

This excludes taking feats or archetypes to get even shorter, of course. Additional effects to get even smaller and incospicuous will be factored in later (*reduce person*, for instance).

I perfectly know being smaller doesn't actually make it easier to hide, unless your Size changes, this is just for roleplaying purposes.

Humanoids from 3.0 are ok as well but please note which one is the smallest viable in 3.5e anyway. Up to now, I found female kobolds to have a lower height limit of 2 feet (around 60 cm).

---

For *alter self* purposes, I'm a medium sized humanoid (human).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The shortest a Medium humanoid can get by using [*alter self*](http://www.d20srd.org/search.htm?q=alter%20self) is 1' 9" tall as a female [grippli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grippli)

Unfortunately, many appropriate humanoids aren't given the [hey-let's-provide-PC-type-information](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#vitalStatistics) treatment that typical Small PC races (e.g. gnomes, halflings) are. One is sometimes left relying on flavor text and outside sources for establishing such creatures' heights.

That said, here's the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* Small humanoids (excluding variants) alphabetically:

- The [**dark creeper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_one_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) (*Fiend Folio* 38) is "stunted," "small and slightly built" according to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. Further information is unavailable in this edition.
- The rock [**gnome**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/gnome.htm) (*Player's Handbook* 109) has a minimum height of 3 ft. 2 in. for males and 3 ft. for females. *Note:* May vary by kind of gnome, but, man, there are a lot of kinds of gnomes.
- The typical [**goblin**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/goblin.htm) (*Monster Manual* 133-4) stands from 3 ft. to 3 ft. 6 in. tall. *Note:* May vary by goblin type, but, man, there are a lot of kinds of goblins.
- The [**grippli**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grippli) (*Dragon* #324 84-87) has a minimum height of 2 ft. for males and 1 ft. 9 in. for females. *Note:* The smallest documented humanoid.
- The stout [**halfling**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfling.htm) (*Player's Handbook* 109) has a minimum height of 2 ft. 10 in. for males and 2 ft. 8 in. for females. *Note:* May vary by kind of halfling, but, man, there are a lot of kinds of halfling.
- The [**kobold**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/kobold.htm) (*Races of the Dragon* 39) has a minimum height of 2 ft. 3 in. for males and a minimum height of 2 ft. for females.
- The [**norker**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norker) (*Dragon* #343 53-4) isn't given an average height in the article "Creature Catalog V." Further information is unavailable in this edition.
- The [**phanaton**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Isle_of_Dread) (*Dragon* #339 62) is "a halfling-sized creature" according to the article "Creature Catalog IV: Campaign Classics." Further information is unavailable in this edition.
- The **poison dusk lizardfolk** (*Monster Manual III* 96-7) is "between 3 to 4 feet in
  height." Further information is unavailable.
- The **vril** (*Drow of the Underdark* 123) is a "small humanoid" but an experiment by drow on goblin stock. Further information is unavailable.
- The [**xvart**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvart) (*Dragon* #339 64) has an average apocryphal height of 3 ft. Further information is unavailable in this edition.

I am happy to update this list with more and better information as it becomes available. Note that according to [Big and Little Creatures in Combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#bigandLittleCreaturesInCombat) the size category Tiny is for creatures 1 ft. to 2 ft. in height or length. Make of that what you will.